# PIXI tilingSprite with variable Background width

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have a problem with PIXI.js. There is a tilingSprite that uses a 1200x1200 image as texture. However the Stage is almost never 1200pixels wide, but responsive to the screen width.
I have a hard time figuring out how to make the tilingSprite always the width of the stage.

Here is my code to generate the tilingSprite.

```
var background,
    backgroundTexture = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage('modules/foo/bar/texture.jpg');

  //backgroundTexture.baseTexture.width = stageWidth;
  //backgroundTexture.update();

  background = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(backgroundTexture, stageWidth, stageHeight);

  return  background;
```

I have already tried applying scale.x and scale.y, setting width of the texture and tilingSprite, fiddling around with the baseTexture.

I would be grateful for any hints.
Used PIXI Version is 3.0.10.

Comment: I have never really done that, so I can't give you a straight definitive answer, but you didn't succeed to do it with scaling? Calculating the amount of scale you need first, setting the scale and re-rendering?
I don't know how tilingSprites work exactly if they automatically scale with the renderer or not (I would assume so), so just setting the background image there and changing the size of renderer / canvas and re-rendering might do it.
Also you could use normal Sprite when the screen is 1200px or less. If the tilingSprite is the one causing issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I calculated the ratio between my texture's size and the size of the background. The important thing to note is that the WebGL renderer requires your background texture resolution to be a power of 2. e.g. 2, 4, 8, 16, 256, 512. Also, if the texture is larger than the screen size, (e.g. 1024 height texture but the screen is only 960 height), then you'll get black bars on the sides. I guess it's not good at downsizing textures, only upsizing them.

Here's code that always stretches the texture to fit the height of the screen, and the tile along the width:

```
var bg, WIDTH, HEIGHT,
    preload = function () {
         bg = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 'background');
    },

    resizeBg = function () {
        // Determine which screen dimension is most constrained
        //var ratio = Math.max(WIDTH / bg.texture.width, HEIGHT / bg.texture.height);

        // always favor height, tile width
        var ratio = HEIGHT / bg.texture.height;

        // Scale the view appropriately to fill that dimension
        bg.scale.x = bg.scale.y = ratio;

        bg.scale.setTo(ratio, ratio);
    },

    resize = function (width, height) {

        //  If the game container is resized this function will be called automatically.
        //  You can use it to align sprites that should be fixed in place and other responsive display things.

        WIDTH = game.width || 540;
        HEIGHT =  game.height || 960;

        if (bg) {
            resizeBg();
        }
    };
```

From http://www.rocketshipgames.com/blogs/tjkopena/2015/09/basic-scaling-animation-and-parallax-in-pixi-js-v3/